# Chrome hover issue with rotated div

Tags: css, google-chrome

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsyo91cs/1/) to illustrate the issue. When you hover over the red box with number 4, you get inconsistent results in Chrome. When the mouse cursor is close to the left edge of the box, the actual element that gets focus is the one beneath the 4 box. When the mouse cursor is close to the right edge of the box, the hover works as expected. Works fine in Firefox.

Three questions:

1. Why this is happening?
2. Is this a bug or a feature? ;)
3. How to fix this?

## HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
<section>
  <div class="page flipped" style="z-index: 30;">
      <figure class="front">1</figure>
      <figure class="back">2</figure>
  </div>
  <div class="page flipped" style="z-index: 31;">
      <figure class="front">3</figure>
      <figure class="back">4</figure>
  </div>
  <div class="page" style="z-index: 1;">
    <figure class="front">5</figure>
    <figure class="back">6</figure>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.wrap { width: 400px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
section {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 200px;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}
.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.page.flipped { transform: rotateY( -180deg ); }

.page.flipped:hover { padding-top: 20px; }

figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

figure.front { background-color: blue; }
figure.back {
    background-color: pink;
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.page:nth-child(2) figure.back {
    background-color: red;
}
```

## Illustration

[image]

### Here is interesting observation:

If I remove the first `.page` (The one beneath, with `z-index: 30`), then it works fine and the rotated div gets the hover event for it's whole area, not only right side. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5eqobLn6/).

But if I change `.page.flipped` rotation from `-180` to `-179` degrees, then some crazy things start to happen when I move my cursor from left to right over red box - it jumps up and down all the time. [Another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6w8c22y/) for that.

Comment: observation: if you remove `backface-visibility: hidden;`, hover-event works for the whole area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug in Chrome. It's fixed in **38.0.2125.101** release.

In one of the Chrome version that I had setting `.page.flipped` rotation to `-181deg` solved the issue too. But this trick didn't work at all on v37.0.2062.120. This one didn't even fire hover event on elements rotated `-181deg`.

Removing `backface-visibility: hidden` was not an option for me because it was causing flickering during animations.